Linking to records in the same object using External ID and SObject Collection REST callout
I am trying to insert records into the RelatedParty__c object in Salesforce. This object has two key fields:

CompositeKey__c (External ID)
Parent__c (Lookup to RelatedParty__c).

My JSON payload contains records referencing other records in the same payload. For example:

Company 123 is the parent of Company ABC.
The records are ordered so dependencies appear higher (e.g., Company 123 is inserted before Company ABC).

To set the Parent__c lookup, I use Parent__r.CompositeKey__c in the JSON payload for Company ABC to reference Company 123. However, Salesforce returns this error:

No such column 'Parent__r.CompositeKey__c' on sobject of type RelatedParty__c.

I also tried using the relationship name Child_Related_Parties__r.CompositeKey__c (from the Parent__c field's details page), but this didn't work either.
I would prefer not to use the Composite API due to its 25-record limit or the Bulk API due to its asynchronous nature.
Is there a way to achieve this with a single synchronous API call?
Here are examples of the payloads I've used:
{
  "allOrNone": true,
  "records": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "RelatedParty__c"
      },
      "Name": "Parent Company",
      "CompanyNumber__c": "542039532",
      "CompositeKey__c": "a0tPv00000EWh9pXXX;FR542039532",
      "Parent__r": null
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "RelatedParty__c"
      },
      "Name": "Child Company",
      "CompanyNumber__c": "433699337",
      "CompositeKey__c": "a0tPv00000EWh9pXXX;FR433699337",
      "Parent__r": {
        "CompositeKey__c": "a0tPv00000EWh9pXXX;FR542039532"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Second attempt
{
  "allOrNone": true,
  "records": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "RelatedParty__c"
      },
      "Name": "Parent Company",
      "CompanyNumber__c": "542039532",
      "CompositeKey__c": "a0tPv00000EWh9pXXX;FR542039532",
      "Parent__r.CompositeKey__c": null
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "RelatedParty__c"
      },
      "Name": "Child Company",
      "CompanyNumber__c": "433699337",
      "CompositeKey__c": "a0tPv00000EWh9pXXX;FR433699337",
      "Parent__r.CompositeKey__c": "a0tPv00000EWh9pXXX;FR542039532"
    }
  ]
}

Edit: I have found using BULK API and using the column titled Parent__r.CompositeKey__c works.

Can you post an example payload you try to use? Do you use it as "Parent__r.CompositeKey__c":"12354747" or as "Parent__r": {"CompositeKey__c" : "12354747"}?

Ive actually tried both examples that you have posted above, the first one returns no such column found and the second shows bad field names on insert/update call: Parent__r"

@kurunve I've added the payloads to the original post.

You can't POST to parent record fields. I think you have no choice but to use a Compsoite or Graph Composite call..

@DavidCheng I'm actually using a PATCH request as its an UPSERT request.

OK, but it's the same reason - you can only insert/update fields in the target object, you can't include fields in the parent object.

@DeploymentFailure did you get a chance to check if my answer resolve the issue?

@Shamina Not yet but I will try this later today.

Assuming the parent record is already created in the database, the first payload attempt was mostly correct except for a syntax issue in parent field for the first block record.
Instead of referencing the relationship field to be null in the parent record, you need to set the field Parent__c itself as null.
So this should normally work:
{
  "allOrNone": true,
  "records": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "RelatedParty__c"
      },
      "Name": "Parent Company",
      "CompanyNumber__c": "542039532",
      "CompositeKey__c": "a0tPv00000EWh9pXXX;FR542039532",
      "Parent__c": null
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "RelatedParty__c"
      },
      "Name": "Child Company",
      "CompanyNumber__c": "433699337",
      "CompositeKey__c": "a0tPv00000EWh9pXXX;FR433699337",
      "Parent__r": {
        "CompositeKey__c": "a0tPv00000EWh9pXXX;FR542039532"
      }
    }
  ]
}

